# Timer callback closes WPF app (DispatcherTimer works..)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, timer

I have a WPF app with a textblock that displays the current time. Said textblock is bound to a DependencyProperty on the ViewModel. Naturally I need to keep updating the time, so I used a timer (System.Threading.Timer) like so:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _dateTimer = new Timer(_dateTimer_Tick, null, 0, 60000);
}

void _dateTimer_Tick(object sender)
{
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
}
```

The thing is, when the callback is called, the app exits... bummer (output says: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll" just when it's about to write to the Time DP).

If I use a DispatcherTimer everything works fine. I don't mind using a DispatcherTimer, it's just that the app is quite big and I wanted to tweak out its performance the best I could. As far as I can see I'm not accessing the UI thread (I'm just updating a property) so a DispatcherTimer wouldn't be needed.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The properties are defined like this:

```
    public string Time
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Time.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

(Date is the same)

Comment: How are the Date and Time properties defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer callback is being executed on a thread which is not the UI thread, this causes problems; the reason this is occurring in spite of the fact that you're 'only updating a property' is because such a call creates a chain of calls, namely to notify interested parties of changes to a property, which in this case is the UI, and consequently the scope bubbles up to cause inappropriate cross-thread calls.

To get over this, you can specify the `Dispatcher` of your `Window` in the timer constructor as the argument for the `state` parameter, then use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

For instance...

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _dateTimer = new Timer(_dateTimer_Tick, Dispatcher, 0, 60000);
}

void _dateTimer_Tick(object state)
{
    ((Dispatcher)state).Invoke(UpdateUI);
}

void UpdateUI()
{
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
}
```

EDIT:

Using a `DispatcherTimer`, as suggested by Henk, and even considered by yourself, may well be the way to go here, however - I simply wasn't aware of the type and therefore was in no position to demonstrate in my answer. With regards to the `DispatcherTimer` and performance, on what grounds is your concern founded?

Comment: So updating the property still counts as accessing the UI thread?

Comment: Correct explanation but the advice would have to be: use DispatcherTimer

Comment: It's just that my app is very UI intensive (lots of pages, lots of controls per page, animations, demonstration mode, interaction via remote devices, etc), and I was trying to get rid of unnecessary "UI stuff"... my concern is probably unfounded, I just thought that since I was just updating the property a 'regular' timer would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Filipe, if indeed there is some performance diference between DispatcherTimer and a regular Timer, anyway WPF uses reflection for data binding, so any performance gain will be negligible in comparison.