# Program hangs on For loop when updating label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop, freeze

I have this code in a winform app:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
 {
      lbl.Text = i.ToString();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
```

I expected to see the label progress from 1 to 20 but instead it just hangs while the for loop is running and then displays a 20, i.e. I don't see 1-19.

Why is this and is there a way to update the label text quickly similar to the milliseconds on an analogue clock (I'm not making a clock, just an example.)

Thanks

**EDIT: This also happens if I have a button with an event that increments the number without Thread.Sleep but I have a beginInvoke to  play a wav file **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Application.DoEvents();` before sleep, that will process all messages in the queue:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
 {
      lbl.Text = i.ToString();
      Application.DoEvents();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are sleeping the gui thread, so before the gui gets to update its slept again.

Try using a timer with a tick of 100ms

Answer (score 2):

The application hangs and you only see `20` simply because this would appear to be executing on the UI thread and you're `Sleep`ing it, and therefore choking the window message loop. However, even if that wasn't the case, you'd most likely only ever see `20` anyway as the loop would execute so fast.

Use a `System.Threading.Timer` to execute every `x` milliseconds and update your label by invoking the appropriate method on the UI thread.

The following post demonstrates how to implement what you might want (albeit in the WPF environment, but the principle is the same - use `ISynchronizeInvoke` for WinForms as opposed to the `Dispatcher` shown in WPF here):

[Timer callback closes WPF app (DispatcherTimer works..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886351/timer-callback-closes-wpf-app-dispatchertimer-works/4886398#4886398)

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer control

```
int i=0;
     private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(i <=20)
                { 
                    lbl.Text = i.ToString(); 
                } 
             i++;
            }
```

Set TimerInterval according to your need (Interval of 1000 = 1 second)